# CSS Footer Hassle - Keeping it down

Tags: html, css, footer

I have been working on a new website and this time using CSS to make it look better. And it so far has done the trick? However I am now stuck. I have built a footer for the bottom of the page (the absolute bottom, not the fixed bottom) and I can't get it to stay down. I have looked at many solutions online but I can't find a solution that has solved the problem.

My footer has a fixed width of 100% and height of 176px so all that is left is to force it to stay at the bottom of the page.

On my webpage, the content is done in the following order.

**Navigation Bar** : This is fixed to the top of the screen, regardless of scrolling
**Slideshow Box** : This is set to absolute and it is given the top value of 80px (height of the Navigation Bar + 16px)
**Content Box** : This is the bulk of the page. It holds all of the page's content (so for About Me, it details about the person). It is set to absolute and it is given the top value of 336px (height of the Navigation Bar + 16px + height of the Slideshow Box + 16px)
**Footer**

The thing is, this whole situation would be solved if I had the height of the Content Box as I could have done the following.

top: 336px + HEIGHT OF CONTENT BOX + 16px;

However, I can't work it out because the Content Box's height is flexible depending on the webpage. It could range from 160px all the way up to 1200px or higher.

Can anyone work out how to solve my problem? I have put the code down below so you can see what I have done.

I appreciate all help! (And just so you know, I am COMPLETELY NEW to CSS. I have only got so far thanks to tutorials online)

```
#navigation-box 
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    min-height: 64px;
    max-height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image:url('Website-Graphics/Navigation_Background.png');

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;

    /* background-color: rgba(157, 157, 157, 1); */
    /* color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 1); */
}

#navigation-box a 
{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation-box a:hover 
{
    color: grey;
}

#slideshow-box
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    min-height: 240px;
    max-height: 240px;
    left: 20%;
    top: 80px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;   
    background-color: rgba(157, 157, 157, 1);;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
}

#content-box
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    min-height: 160px;
    left: 20%;
    top: 336px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
}

#footer-box 
{
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 176px;
    max-height: 176px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 3px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;

    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

body 
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image:url('Website-Graphics/Main_Background.png');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should keep the footer at the bottom regardless of the window height

```
<div id="footer">myfooter</div>
```

Css

```
#footer {
   position : absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   background-color:red;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: That has done the trick! At least a scrolling footer will look good!

Though is there anyway to fix it to the bottom of the page rather than the bottom of the screen?